# How to get list from string which you pre splitted?

Tags: python, string, list, split

So there is a string `foo = 'asdfasdfzxc<test>afx<one>'`
How to get `bar = ['asdfasdfzxc','test','afx','one']` ?

Comment: you want to remove the last 3 letters?

Comment: What is the logic of getting `bar` from `foo`?

Comment: what happens to `afx`?

Comment: @user3080953 mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
import re
foo = 'asdfasdfzxc<test>afx<one>'
bar = re.split(r'[\<\>]',foo)[:-1]
bar.remove('afx')

bar
Out[89]:
['asdfasdfzxc', 'test', 'one']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
foo = 'asdfasdfzxc<test>afx<one>'
bar= foo.replace('<','>').split('>')[:-1]
del bar[2]
```

Comment: If you're going to do that - it'd probably be worth considering using `.replace(">", "<").split("<")` instead. One less replace call, and you don't catch any `.`s that may have been desirable.

Comment: Good idea. Will change it.